# vuetify v-menu how to make custom elevation?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify and v-menu like from the docs here

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/

I am confused on how I can make the elevation only show up on the bottom left and right, If I apply a class "elevation-2" to my v-menu for example, the elevation shows up everywhere but I just want it on the left, right, and bottom.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think adding `elevation-2` to v-menu do you any good. I would rather to add a css class selector to the `v-btn` and use box shadow. I add a css class selector `test-btn` to my `v-btn` and then in the styles I add a box shadow like this:

```
.test-btn {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 11px 20px -3px #000000;
  box-shadow: 1px 11px 20px -3px #000000;
}
```

If you are not familiar with box shadow in css, you can use generator websites like [this](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/).

Comment: this still leaves some shadow at the top for me, im looking for the one that has no shadow at the top

Comment: Yes.
I wanted to show that with box-shadow you can add the shadows wherever you want. You can go the site I added, and create any shadow you like and need.